# Find acceleration time graph from acceleration distance graph

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, kinematics

Let $$a=mx-c$$ where $m,c$ are both positive.

I want to find the acceleration time-graph so I did:

\begin{align}
a & =mx-c, \\
v \frac{dv}{dx}
 & =mx-c , \quad \text{then:}\\
v^2 & =mx^2-cx+c_1, \\
\end{align}

but I couldn't go any further.
Can you help please

Comment: Without an initial position and velocity, there is nothing more that you can do. The trajectory will change with the initial point, and so will the acceleration-time-behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your differential equation is
$$
\ddot x(t)=a(x(t))=mx(t)-c
$$
so multiplication with $\dot x$ and integration leads to the energy level of the solution
$$
E=\frac12 \dot x^2-\frac m2\left(x-\frac cm\right)^2
$$
Now you need to solve the first order differential equation
$$
\dot x(t)=\pm\sqrt{E+m\left(x-\frac cm\right)^2}
$$
Try the substitution $x=\frac cm+a\sinh(u)$ for $E\ne 0$.
Inserting its solution into $a(x(t))$ will give you the general acceleration-time relation.